# incorrect syntax error and object/column name missing

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I'm making a storet procedure that basicly just does 1 dynamic query with the result from another dynamic query as alias for 1 column.
However, I get the following two errors (id doesn't say where):

1. Incorrect syntax near '='.
2. An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

This is my code:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE myProcedure
        @param1 NVARCHAR(50),
        @param2 NVARCHAR(50),
        @param3 int
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @query Nvarchar(2000)
        DECLARE @columnName Nvarchar(250)
        DECLARE @columnNameOUT Nvarchar(250)
        set @columnName = ''
        SELECT @query = 'SELECT (@columnNameOUT = CONVERT(time(0), TimeStamps."timeStamp", 108)) AS alias FROM TimeStamps WHERE [param3] = ''' + CAST(@param3 AS VARCHAR) + ''' AND param2 = ''' + @param2 + ''' AND [param1] = ''' + @param1 +''''
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@columnNameOUT NVARCHAR(30) OUTPUT', @columnNameOUT = @columnName OUTPUT
        set @query = ''
        IF @param1 IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @query = 'SELECT column1 AS '''+@columnName+''', column2, column3 ETA FROM myTable WHERE [param3] = '''+CAST(@param3 AS VARCHAR) +''' AND param2 = '''+@param2+''' AND [param1] IS NULL order by column1'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @query = 'SELECT column1 AS '''+@columnName+''', column2, column3 ETA FROM myTable WHERE [param3] = '''+CAST(@param3 AS VARCHAR) +''' AND param2 = '''+@param2+''' AND [param1] ) '''+@param1+''' order by column1'
        END
        EXEC(@query);
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it myself!

Turns out that this little query:

```
SELECT @query = 'SELECT (@columnNameOUT = CONVERT(time(0), TimeStamps."timeStamp", 108)) AS alias FROM TimeStamps WHERE [param3] = ''' + CAST(@param3 AS VARCHAR) + ''' AND param2 = ''' + @param2 + ''' AND [param1] = ''' + @param1 +''''
```

Had a chance of returning empty. So after adding a `IF @columnName = ''` everything worked out.

And changing this line:

```
... 'SELECT (@columnNameOUT = CONVERT(time(0), TimeStamps."timeStamp", 108)) AS alias FROM ...
```

To this:

```
...'SELECT @columnNameOUT = CONVERT(time(0), TimeStamps."timeStamp", 108) FROM...
```

Made the other error disappear too :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a problem with bracket:

```
' AND [param1] ) '
```

Your second problem was in ELSE statement (there is a solution):

```
    BEGIN
        SELECT @query = 'SELECT column1, column2, column3 ETA 
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE [param3] = '''+CAST(@param3 AS VARCHAR) +''' 
        AND [param2] = '''+@param2+''' 
        AND [param1] = '''+@param1+''' order by column1';
    END
```

But the first problem looks like here, but don't know how to fix it:

```
SELECT @query = 'SELECT (@columnNameOUT = CONVERT(time(0), TimeStamps."timeStamp", 108)) AS alias
```

Hope it could help you

Comment: thanks, But I still get the same errors after fixing all of those